# Process.Start() Leaves Application non-responsive to file open events from windows explorer

Tags: c#, process.start

The issue I have been having is that when launching the other program (DPlot) it becomes unresponsive to requests from windows explorer to open its file type (.GRF)

I've boiled down the code to only what is required for the sake of debugging it.

```
// initialize and start dplot
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key =
    Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    "Software\\DPLOT\\shell\\open\\command", false);

string exePath = key.GetValue(null) as string;

Process dplot = new Process();
dplot.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
dplot.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
dplot.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
dplot.Start();
```

If I launch DPlot via `Process.Start()`, double clicking on a .GRF file (which windows knows to open in DPlot) does not open the file. Same story when dragging/dropping onto the DPlot window.

If I close the window opened by the code, and double click on a .GRF file, the file opens in DPlot as expected. If I launch the program from the windows bar, I can then double click on a .GRF file and it will open in DPlot as expected.

Is this an issue with how I am launching the application? Or an issue with the application itself?

EDIT: DPlot also contains a DDE that I have tried using, to launch DPlot in the DDE looks like this:

```
int wasActive = 0;
dplot.DPlot_FindDPLOTLIB();
dplot.DPlot_Start(0, ref wasActive);
```

Comment: if you change the line `dplot.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` to `dplot.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`, does that solve your issue?

Comment: Don't forget to close/dispose `key`; registry keys are unmanaged resources and must be released. Not sure but it might help with your issue, since the key you are accessing tells Windows how to open the file.

Comment: Also, what is the string value of `exePath`? General such a registry value would contain the full path to the executable, plus some other characters (i.e. %1). I've never actually tried assigning such a string to the `StartInfo.FileName` property, but that may be something to look at. Instead of getting the registry value, try just hardcoding the path to the executable, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Nik That line is actually an artifact of trying both true and false with no success. The string `exePath` is equal to `"\"C:\\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\\DPLOT\\DPLOT.EXE\""` I have tried hard-coding the path with no success.

@JohnWu Thank you for the advice, I should be doing this anyways, but unfortunately, this is not the root cause.

Comment: If I compile the code and run the executable standalone, the issue does NOT persist. It seems to be some artifact of Visual Studio 2012??